# How to use Castle Windsor typed factory in this case?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, castle-windsor

Simple DI example:

```
public interface INumberToWordConverter
{
    string ConvertNumber(int number);
}

public interface IOutputManager
{
    void Write<T>(string who, T what);
}

public interface INumberProvider
{
    int GenerateNumber();
}

public class PlayWithDI
{
    private IOutputManager _outputManagerService;
    private INumberProvider _numberProviderService;
    private INumberToWordConverter _numberToWordConverterService;

    private PlayWithDI() { }
    public PlayWithDI(
        IOutputManager outputManagerService,
        INumberProvider numberProviderService,
        INumberToWordConverter numberToWordConverterService)
    {
        if (outputManagerService == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(outputManagerService));
        if (numberProviderService == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(numberProviderService));
        if (numberToWordConverterService == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(numberToWordConverterService));

        _outputManagerService = outputManagerService;
        _numberProviderService = numberProviderService;
        _numberToWordConverterService = numberToWordConverterService;
    }

    public void Execute()
    {
        int number = _numberProviderService.GenerateNumber();
        string wordOfNumber = _numberToWordConverterService.ConvertNumber(number);
        _outputManagerService.Write(nameof(PlayWithDI), wordOfNumber);
    }
```

Example implementations (just ctors):

```
// Implements INumberProvider
public RandomNumberProvider(
        int min, int max,
        IOutputManager outputManagerService)
{
    ...
}

// Implements INumberToWordConverter
public ItalianNumberToWordConverter(
      IOutputManager outputManagerService)
{
    ...
}

// Implements IConsoleManager
public ConsoleOutputManager()
{
    ...
}
```

If I know which `min` and `max` give to `RandomNumberProvider`, I would just resolve like this:

```
    public void Install(
        IWindsorContainer container, 
        IConfigurationStore store)
    {
        container.Register(
            Component.For<PlayWithDI>());

        container.Register(
            Component.For<IOutputManager>()
            .ImplementedBy<ConsoleOutputManager>());

        container.Register(
            Component.For<INumberProvider>()
            .ImplementedBy<RandomNumberProvider>()
            .DependsOn(
                Dependency.OnValue("min", 2),
                Dependency.OnValue("max", 20)));

        container.Register(
            Component.For<INumberToWordConverter>()
            .ImplementedBy<ItalianNumberToWordConverter>());
    }

...
container.Install(new DependenciesConfiguration1());
var testDI = container.Resolve<PlayWithDI>();
testDI.Execute();
```

The problem arises when I want to give custom parameters to `RandomNumberProvider` at runtime.

I took a look at `TypedFactory`, but I don't really understand it in this example, because if I resolve a factory first, how should I then resolve PlayWithDi? Should I pass to its constructor an INumberProviderFactory instead of an INumberProvider?

In this case I thought about a factory like this:

```
public interface INumberProviderFactory
{
    INumberProvider Create(
        IOutputManager outputManager, 
        int min, int max);
}
```

When I'll then call `Create`, how should I resolve the `outputManager` then? I'm confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem arises when I want to give custom parameters to RandomNumberProvider at runtime.

This is where you go wrong. [Injecting runtime data into components during construction is ananti-pattern](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=99):

> Don't inject runtime data into application components during construction; it causes ambiguity, complicates the composition root with an extra responsibility and makes it extraordinarily hard to verify the correctness of your DI configuration. [...] Let runtime data flow through the method calls of constructed object graphs.

In other words, your `RandomNumberProvider` should accept the `min` and `max` arguments is input parameters on the `GenerateNumber` method.